# Adding web.config to ASP.NET Data Access Component

Tags: asp.net, web-config

How do I add a web.config to a class library? I'm trying to build a data access component with two classes, one class that represents one thing and the other to perform data operations on that thing. However when I right click the project and click add item, I don't see information for adding a web.config, I just see information for adding an app.config. Maybe I'm doing this wrong? I'd like this component to be available to other asp.net apps that I will build in the future....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add a config file to a dll, because you can't directly execute a dll.  Config files are for executables and web sites.

If you want to create a reference config, that just gives an example of how the config settings for your dll should look, then try creating a text file.

Comment: I think I may have been mistaken. In my component's constructor I need to get connection string information, so I guess I would just call WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[""].ConnectionString for the related web app?

Comment: Yes, or you could pass it in as an argument in your constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to add a web.config?  All you would need to be able to make the component available to other ASP.NET apps is add a reference, either to the project or the dll itself.